# $f(m+f(n))-f(m)=n$

Tags: functions, integers

Question :

> Find all functions $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ from the integers to the integers satisfying
> $$
> f(m+f(n))-f(m)=n
> $$
> for all integers $m, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

---

My Work :
We know, $f(m+f(n))=f(m)+n$ and $f(n+f(m))=f(n)+m$. From this we get $$f(f(n+f(m)))=f(m+f(n))=n+f(m) \implies f(f(x))=x \implies \text{f is bijective}$$
Also, putting $m=n$ in the original equation, we get $$f(m+f(m))=m+f(m)$$ . Substituting $x=m+f(m)$, we get $f(x)=x$, but the Answer key says $f(x)=-x$ is also another solution, where did I miss this?

Answer (score 1):

From $f(m+f(m))=m+f(m)$ you've concluded that $f(x)=x$, by "substituting $x=m+f(m)$". But this doesn't follow. The claim $f(x)=x$ is shorthand for the assertion "for *every* $x$, $f(x)=x$". When you name $m+f(m)$ as $x$, you have no idea if that $x$ does indeed cover all possible integers. You haven't shown that $f(x)=x$ for all $x$, only for those $x$'s which happen to have the form $m+f(m)$.

And indeed, when $f(x)=-x$, what are those numbers of the form $m+f(m)$?

Comment: +1 , this is where OP was going wrong. It will indicate that $f(0) = 0$ here. More generally , it will indicate that $f$ has at least 1 fixed Point. Alternatively , OP might use $f(f(x)) = x$ to get something like $c^2x = x$ where $c = \pm1$ !

Comment: That's why I proved $f$ is bijective. Now I know $f$ covers all integers, so does $m+f(m)$ right?

Comment: No, not right, as you can plainly see from the example $f(m)=-m$. In this case $f(m)$ itself is a bijection, but $f(m)+m$ most certainly isn't.

Comment: Elaborating : Here $m$ covers all Integers , $f(m)$ covers all Integers , while $x=m+f(m)$ may or may not cover all Integers. When $f(m)=m$ , $x$ covers all Integers. When $f(m)=-m$ , $x$ "covers" only $0$. Alternatively , $f(m)=cm$ , then $f(f(m))=c^2m=m$ , then $c=\pm1$ : DONE

Comment: Correction : [....] When $f(m)=m$ , $x=m+f(m)=m+m=2m$ covers all EVEN Integers [....] : Either way $x$ is not covering all Integers.

Comment: @Prem Why $f(m)=cm$?

Comment: The Concern about not covering all Integers should be resolved by now. I gave the **Alternate Partial Solution** where we assume $f$ is Polynomial , then show that it must be linear & then show that the Constant must be $0$ to leave $f(m)=cm$ : Eventually , we will get $c^2=1$ !

Comment: @Prem yes that concern indeed is resolved, but about your partial solution, why should we assume $f$ to be a polynomial?

Comment: That unproved **Assumption** is "Precisely" why it is **Partial Solution** , @zaemon_23 , We will have more work to show that it is Polynomial. Beyond that , it is very easy.

Answer (score 0):

The symmetrization of $f(m+f(n))=f(m)+n$ gives the equation
$$
f(f(n+f(m)) = f(m+f(n)) = n+f(m)
$$
so that if $x=n+f(m)$ then $f(f(x))=x$. But since you are free to choose *both* $n$ and $m$, this implies $f(f(k))=k$ for all $k\in \mathbb Z$ (*e.g.* given $k\in \mathbb Z$ if you take $m=0$ and $n=k-f(0)$, then $k=n+f(m)$).

On the other hand, once you have $f(f(n))=n$ so that $f$ is bijective, then the identity $f$ must satisfy can be written as
$$
f(m+f(n))= f(m)+n = f(m)+f(f(n)),  
$$
and so, for any $a,b \in  \mathbb Z$, taking $m=a$ and $n=f(b)$ (so $b=f(n)$) we have $f(a+b) = f(a)+f(b)$, that is, $f$ is a automorphism of the abelian group $\mathbb Z$, hence $f(n) = \pm n$.